# Generate dynamic SQL query with multiple filter option(from application)added in single CLOB - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There is application in which filter option includes start date, end date, postcode, etc where user can select multiple option from single filter. Ex: User can select 5 different start date, end date and 3 different postcode or can select 1 start date, end date and no postcode. There are 7 other filters and each filter user can select multiple options. (Consider E-Commerce website like Amazon. If you want to buy mobile, you use filter for camera range like 16MP,32MP,48MP and company like 'Samsung','Motorola', 'Nokia' and similarly for processor and screen size as well. So as a developer you want to store all the value in CLOB and give the result)

Input will come something like

```
<date>
<start_date>01/01/2019</start_date>
<end_date>31/01/2019</end_date>
<start_date>01/03/2019</start_date>
<end_date>31/03/2019</end_date>
<start_date>01/05/2019</start_date>
<end_date>31/05/2019</end_date>
</date>
<pc>
<postcode>56012</postcode>
<postcode>56000</postcode>
<postcode>56234</postcode>
</pc>
```

Now my query should look something like

select col1,col2,col3 from table_name where between start_date and end_date and between start_date and end_date... and postcode like '56012' and postcode like '56000'

Result set retruned should again be sent in clob.

Is there any way out to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure get_data(p_filter IN clob, p_result clob)
is
v_query clob;
V_condition clob;
v_lp_cnt integer;
v_result clob;
v_where_clause clob;
begin

--Considering output will be returned in XML
v_query := 'SELECT XMLELEMENT (
"data", XMLAGG 
    (XMLELEMENT
        (
  "whole_data",
  XMLELEMENT ("final_date", final_date),
  ......... from table_name where col2='xyz'';

--Considering that filter values will be less than 1000
--date

V_condition  := NULL;
v_lp_cnt  := 0;

FOR crec IN(SELECT t.start_date, t.end_date
                   FROM XMLTABLE('/Filter/final_date/Date' 
                   PASSING xmltype(p_filter)
                   COLUMNS 
                   start_date VARCHAR2(240) PATH 'Start_Date',
                   end_date VARCHAR2(240) PATH 'End_Date')t
                   WHERE 1 = 1
                  )

loop
v_lp_cnt  := v_lp_cnt +1;
        
        IF   v_lp_cnt =1
        THEN
            v_condition  := ' AND (ext.final_date between to_date('''|| crec.start_date ||''',''dd/mm/yyyy'') and to_date('''|| crec.end_date ||''',''dd/mm/yyyy'')';
        v_where_clause := v_where_clause||v_condition;  
        v_condition:= null;
        
        ELSIF (v_lp_cnt >1 and v_lp_cnt <1000)
        THEN
        v_condition  := ' OR ext.final_date between to_date('''|| crec.start_date ||''',''dd/mm/yyyy'') and to_date('''|| crec.end_date ||''',''dd/mm/yyyy'')';
        v_where_clause := v_where_clause||v_condition; 
       end if;

end loop;
IF v_lp_cnt>0 
THEN
v_where_clause := v_where_clause|| ')';

END IF;

--postcode

v_condition  := NULL;
v_lp_cnt  := 0;

FOR crec IN(SELECT  (t.postcode) postcode 
                   FROM XMLTABLE('/Filter/pc/postcode' 
                   PASSING xmltype(p_filter)
                    COLUMNS postcode VARCHAR2(30)PATH '/postcode')t
                    WHERE 1 = 1
                  )

loop
        v_lp_cnt := v_lp_cnt + 1;

   IF v_lp_cnt = 1 THEN
   v_condition  := ' AND (postcode in ('''|| crec.postcode ||'''';
   v_where_clause := v_where_clause||v_condition;
   v_condition  := NULL;
         
   ELSE  
   v_condition   := v_condition||','||''''|| crec.postcode ||'''';
   v_where_clause := v_where_clause||v_condition;
   v_condition  := NULL;
        
   END IF;
        
END LOOP;


IF v_lp_cnt >0
THEN
   v_where_clause := v_where_clause||v_condition||'))';
       
end if;  


v_query := v_query || v_where_clause;

execute immediate v_query into v_result;

p_result := v_result;

end;
```